# Convergence of $\sum |a_n|$

Tags: convergence-divergence, absolute-convergence

I have question about convergence of $\sum |a_n|$,

$1.$ If $\sum |a_n|$  converges then $\sum a_n^k$ converges of any $K \in N$,

my reasoning was, an $\sum |a_n| $ converges which means $\exists N$ such that $\forall n > N,  $   $|a_n| < 1$.,

so any $K \in N$, $a_n^k \leq |a_n|$ that's because of  $|a_n|<1$ $\forall n>N$.

so $\sum_{N+1}^{\infty} a_n^k$  $\leq$  $ \sum_{N+1}^{\infty}|a_n|$, so by direct comparison test $\sum a_n^k$ converges.

correct me if i was wrong.

Comment: You need to make a change $a_n^k$ to $|a_n^k|$.

Comment: why, i mean isn't every time $a_n^k  \leq |a_n|$?

Comment: $a_n^k\le |a_n|$ is true but is not enough for concluding the convergence of $\sum a_n^k$. If you put the absolute value on $a_n^k$, then it proves the absolute convergence of $\sum a_n^k$, thus implying convergence of $\sum a_n^k$.

Comment: any specific reason as its not enough for concluding the convergence of $\sum a_n^k$

Comment: $a_n^k\leq |a_n|$ only gives proof that partial sums of $a_n^k$ is at most partial sums of $|a_n|$. Thus, this does not provide the lower bound result. So, the inequality alone does not rule out possibility of the sum diverging to $-\infty$.

Comment: Got it know, thank you :)